# Meta commands in Psycopg2 - \d not working

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I wish to list all the column names of a table using `psycopg2` package of Python (2.7). But I am unable to execute the following query -

```
cur.execute("\d my_table");
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "\"
```

Is there an alternate as to how I can list the column names of a table using `psycopg2` ? Please point out any duplicates. Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Command line `psql` has some shortcuts like `\d` but it's not part of SQL. What you need is to query `information_schema`:

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'my_table';
```

**EDIT:** It's really an important information that the command line `psql -E` will echo SQL queries used to implement `\d` and other backslash commands (whenever you use one of them in the psql prompt) as @piro has written in comment. This way you get what you want very easily.
*Thanks @piro!*

Comment: None. But everething you can do with meta commands is also available by querying `information_schema` and/or `pg_catalog`.

Comment: note that `psql -E` will emit the query used internally to implement `\d` and the other backslash commands, which is super-handy to explore the `pg_catalog`.